# (Python, Twitch Bot) Having troubles implementing AutoMod

Tags: python, twitch

I'm currently coding a Twitch Moderation bot for my streams, and I'm running into a bit of an issue - the automod part of it isn't working. I can't at all figure out what is making it not work.

Here's my code:

```py
@bot.event()
async def event_message(message):
  print(f"Message detected:\nSender: {message.author.name}\nContent: {message.content}")


  for word in banned_words:
    if word in message.content.lower():
      print("I deleted that message.")
    
      await message.send(f"/timeout {message.author.name} 3s You sent a non-family-friendly word, but we're a family-friendly channel.")
      await message.send("f ¦ [Purge, 3s TO]")
```

And this is what is appearing in the console:

```
Message detected:
Sender: slend_k
Content: [the swear word I sent - I changed it because, well, it's a swear]
I deleted that message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twitchio/client.py", line 190, in wrapped
    await func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 28, in event_message
    await message.send(f"/timeout {message.author.name} 3s You sent a non-family-friendly word, but we're a family-friendly channel.")
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I have no clue what is causing this problem, as I know for a fact that `message` does have the attribute `send`.
I tried it with `ctx.send` but that gave me the same error in the console.

Thanks for any help provided! :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Twitch-IO doesn't support sending messages in channels without ctx. If this is just moderating for your chat, here's a solution involving websocket-client:

```
from websocket import create_connection

irc = "your irc token"
bot_username = "your bot's username"
streamer_username = "your username"

def timeout(timeout_username):
    ws = create_connection('wss://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv')
    ws.send(f"PASS {irc}")
    ws.send(f'NICK {bot_username}')
    ws.send(f"PRIVMSG #{streamer_username} :/timeout {timeout_username} 3s You sent a non-family-friendly word, but we're a family-friendly channel.")
    ws.close()
```

If you just run that function any time you want to time someone out, it should do the trick! This was an issue I was having for a while too, so I understand the frustration